# JSP static import performance overview

Tags: html, jsp

I understand that in JSP the best practice is to generally put all the scripts to the bottom of the page, so that the page html/css can load fast faster, while the scripts are still loading.

The thing that interest me: what if you have *includes* in your JSP file like this:

```
<%@ include file="a.jsp" %>
<%@ include file="b.jsp" %>
<%@ include file="c.jsp" %>
```

It is better in terms of code modularity, but in terms of performance? Will these scripts all get loaded any time the user calls the page, or are they preloaded at the compile?

Is that better performance-wise than having all the scripts defined in the bottom of a single JSP file?

Comment: Those includes are brought in on the server side not the client. The practice of putting scripts (meaning javascript) at the end of the page is for client side optimization and has nothing to do with these server-side includes.

Comment: JSP include is "evalueted" only once by first request (during compilation).